# How to prevent negative number in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have data which is starting from 0 in my database.

My php will add 1 or -1 to the data depending on the user's input. 
My problem is that if data is 0 and a user try to subtract 1. The data become 4294967295 
which is the maximum value of INT data type. Are there anyways to make the data 
stays in 0 even when the user asks for -1? Thanks for the reply..

my sql command is like below

```
update board set score=score-1 where team='TeamA'
//this would generate 4294967295 if the score is 0.....
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes..

```
UPDATE board SET score = score - 1 WHERE team = 'TeamA' AND score > 0
```

Answer (score 3):

```
update board set score=score-1 
where team='TeamA'
and score > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add AND SCORE > 0

Answer (score 1):

Other solution to Jerry's question is to use MySQL "CAST" (if want to reduce the amount until it reach zero (but no more)):

```
UPDATE board SET score = CAST(score - 1 AS SIGNED) WHERE team = 'TeamA'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE board MODIFY score UNSIGNED INT;
```

Comment: It's already an unsigned int; he's trying to prevent his UPDATE from underflowing a row that has a 0 score (the title is admittedly confusing)

Comment: He's saying he's getting 4294967295  so I assume it is unsigned but wrapping around.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set your column as unsigned?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using transactional database (like InnoDB), you can do something like:

```
SQL> START TRANSACTION;
SQL> UPDATE board SET score=score-1 WHERE team="TeamA"
SQL> SELECT @@warning_count as wc
if($row["wc"] > 0) {
  $error = true;
SQL> ROLLBACK;
} else
SQL> COMMIT;
```

It is just the logic, not the actually implementation.

It may not be very useful for the mentioned question, but it works in other situations in which you can not allow negative numbers and you need an error to be raised, for example, if you have a shopping cart and need to update stock quantities of all selected products, you need to perform several UPDATE queries at once. Any of the above solutions will just SKIP updating the product and will not return in any error message. Of course there are many way to prevent that (like locking the table and reading the quantity before updating), but this is a quick (an neat) solution. You may use "SHOW WARNINGS" instead of "SELECT @@warning_count" if you need the warning code/description.